# Powershell - Monitoring folder Content

Tags: powershell, directory, monitoring, powershell-3.0

I would like to be able to monitor the changes in a folder for a short period of time when a lot of files will be created and other changes will be made.

The code below is working but doesn't catch all the changes.

```
$folder = ’C:\Data’
$timeout = 1000
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder
Write-Host ”Press CTRL+C to abort monitoring $folder”
while ($true) {
$result = $FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged(‘all’, $timeout)
if ($result.TimedOut -eq $false)
{
Write-Warning (‘File {0} : {1}’ -f $result.ChangeType, $result.name)
}
}
Write-Host ’Monitoring aborted.’
```

If I use this on `C:\Data` it works **but**:

I create a .txt and it says 2 times `new text document.txt`. 
Then I fill the name for the new txt and it outputs it 3 times. Or the other way around.

Please see below the output of

- creating a `hello.txt` in my folder
- creating a new folder with the name `HiThere` and
- then renaming `hello.txt` to `someTxt.txt`
- then deleting them both

**output:**

```
`Press CTRL+C to abort monitoring C:\Data
WARNING: File Created : New Text Document.txt
WARNING: File Changed : New Text Document.txt
WARNING: File Changed : New Text Document.txt
WARNING: File Changed : hello.txt
WARNING: File Created : New folder
WARNING: File Renamed : HiThere
WARNING: File Renamed : someTxt.txt
WARNING: File Changed : someTxt.txt
WARNING: File Changed : someTxt.txt
WARNING: File Changed : someTxt.txt
WARNING: File Deleted : someTxt.txt
WARNING: File Deleted : HiThere`
```

**More problems**: If I use this on a newtwork drive then not all the changes are being catched. (And this would be the point of this script, to monitor a folder from a mapped drive).

*Test the code on your machine* by only changing the folder path.

Using Powershell ISE 3.0

Comment: Note that the FileSystemWatcher is notoriously unreliable, it is usually recommended to use different methods for monitoring the filesystem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider hi, thank you for your replay. I see, didn't know that, however maybe someone has an idea to improve the code a bit. I am mostly playing around with powershell and trying to find new cool ways to use it. Stummbled upon this little project and thought to give it a go. If there isn't a solution to this, I will let it go, but not yet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insted of the while($true) loop, have you tried the "Register-ObjectEvent"?

I just tested one of my script using this method and could easily take 2000 empty files (generated in powershell). Unfortunatly, this was on a local machine.

Instructions: Define function like normal and off you go.
The command you use is:

```
Start-BackupScript -WatchFolder "C:\temp\my watch folder\" -DestinationFolder "C:\temp\backup\"
```

The script now monitors "C:\temp\my watch folder\" for new files created in that specific folder and will move them to "C:\temp\backup\". It will also append the date and time to the file.

Lets say you have started the script with the parameters above. You now place "hello_world.txt" in the watch folder. The script will move the file to "C:\temp\backup\" with the new filename being: "hello_world_2016-02-10_10-00-00.txt"

The script runs in the background. If you want to know how it's doing, then use the command:

```
Get-Job $backupscript -Keep
```

There you can see what it has been doing when. Please note that the -Keep parameter keeps the output in the "log", so you can check it later.

Script:

```
function Start-BackupScript
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param
  (
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$WatchFolder,
    [Parameter()]
    [String]$DestinationFolder
    )
  Process 
  {
    $filter = '*.*'                           
    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $WatchFolder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,     LastWrite'} 
    $action = {
      $fileMissing = $false 
      $FileInUseMessage = $false 
      $copied = $false 
      $file = Get-Item $Args.FullPath 
      $dateString = Get-Date -format "_yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss" 
      $DestinationFolder = $event.MessageData 
      $DestinationFileName = $file.basename + $dateString + $file.extension 
      $resultfilename = Join-Path $DestinationFolder $DestinationFileName 
      Write-Output ""
      while(!$copied) { 
        try { 
          Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $resultfilename -ErrorAction Stop
          $copied = $true 
        }  
        catch [System.IO.IOException] { 
          if(!$FileInUseMessage) { 
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd @ HH:mm:ss") - $file in use. Waiting to move file"
            $FileInUseMessage = $true 
          } 
          Start-Sleep -s 1 
        }  
        catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] { 
          $fileMissing = $true 
          $copied = $true 
        } 
      } 
      if($fileMissing) { 
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd @ HH:mm:ss") - $file not found!"
      } else { 
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd @ HH:mm:ss") - Moved $file to backup! `n`tFilename: `"$resultfilename`""
      }
    }
    $backupscript = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName "Created" -Action $action -MessageData $DestinationFolder
    Write-Host "Started. WatchFolder: `"$($WatchFolder)`" DestinationFolder: `"$($DestinationFolder)`". Job is in: `$backupscript"
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't before, but since you mentioned it, I have now :) I'm not sure how to use it (i simply replaced it like you said). I am getting this message `supply values for the following parameters: eventName: ` What should I pass there? From a quick read, I see that I could pass a variable in the do block by using the `-MessageData parameter`.  Can't quite solve it though. How did you do it?

Comment: I just added my script to the post. Please note that $action is a script block that is executed every time there is a file created.

Comment: thank you. Could you write a brief `how to use` instruction/s attached to it? For both me and future readers

Comment: I have updated the post once again. Feel free to give any feedback.

Comment: by changing the `@{IncludeSubdirectories = $false` to `true` and by changing `move-item` to `copy-item` is quite close to what i was looking for. Except for the log. I was also hoping for a log with the changes. But nevertheless, you solution is nice and you diserve an accepted answer. Feel free to bring improvements if you wish.

Comment: i'm trying to fix now the subdirectories, since it doesn't seem to copy the entire folder. Just some random file from it.

Comment: Also, trying to modify it to alert on delete, or perform some sort of alert on delete

Comment: Well if want subdirectories, than change it to `$true`.

If you want folders, I believe you can change the `$filter` variable to `'*'`.

For the logging, well you can write whatever you want. Just change the Write-Output variables to what you want.

If you want delete then add it to the arraylist `EventName`. Read the eventnames in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Register-WMIEvent?

Something like this:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' and TargetInstance.Path = '\\Users\\Administrator\\' and targetInstance.Drive = 'C:' and (targetInstance.Extension = 'txt' or targetInstance.Extension = 'doc' or targetInstance.Extension = 'rtf') and targetInstance.LastAccessed > '$($cur)' " -sourceIdentifier "Accessor" -Action $action   `
```

You can monitor a folder and then specific extensions within the folder. And then you set up a PowerShell scriptblock to handle any accesses. There's more here on this if you're interested: https://blog.varonis.com/practical-powershell-for-it-security-part-i-file-event-monitoring/

Agree with some of the comments above that file monitoring is not reliable -- lags and hiccups.  Anywyay, hope this helps.